# Getting error when fire insert query in nodejs.db2

Tags: node.js, db2, web-development-server

I am trying to fire insert query through my node server and getting the below mentioned error message.
I tried to execute same query in DB@ editor,it works fine there. Please help me out

Query i am using:

```
INSERT  INTO  "PNH31288"."LOGIN"("NAME","EMAIL","IS_VERIFIED","PSWD") VALUES('Nizar','kadrin@uwindsor.ca',TRUE,'1234')
```

My connection string:

var connStr = "DATABASE=" + process.env['DATABASE'] + ";HOSTNAME="+process.env['HOSTNAME']+ ";UID=" +
process.env['UID'] + ";PWD=" + process.env['PWD'] + ";PORT=" + process.env['PORT'] + ";PROTOCOL=" + process.env['PROTOCOL'];

Error:

```
{ **[Error: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1337N  The service "undefined" was not found.
]**
  error: '[node-ibm_db] SQL_ERROR',
  **sqlcode: -1337,**
  message:
   '[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1337N  The service "undefined" was not found.\r\n',
  state: '08001' }
```

My code snippet:

```
    var insertQuery = `INSERT  INTO  "PNH31288"."LOGIN"("NAME","EMAIL","IS_VERIFIED","PSWD") VALUES('Nizar','${userEmail}',TRUE,'${userPswd}')`  
    ibmdb.open(connStr).then(
    conn => {conn.query(insertQuery).then(data => 
    {
    console.log(data);
    conn.closeSync();
    },
    err => 
    {
    console.log(err);
    });
    }, err => 
    {
    console.log(err)
    }
    );
    res.status(201).send({ data:receivedOTP });
```

Comment: Why did you tag postgresql?

Comment: Edit your question to ADD missing information:  your connection string.  The Db2-driver is telling you that it cannot interpret your connection string (actually that it cannot resolve the port-number/service-name).

Comment: Okay I will check that,Thanks

Comment: You have not shown your __actual__ connection string, you only show how you construct this string (but not the result). Possibly some values are empty or have unexpected or malformed values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake, actually I had entered wrong port number, instead of 50000 , I had entered 5000. So yea one thing got cleared that this kind of error appears when we enter wrong port number. Thanks for the help guys.